# can't understand http request problem though it works fine last 7 days ago in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, listview, request, dio

I made a http request using dio. and it displayed as listview in flutter app. it works fine in my project properly. but since last 7 days it shows problem. i can't understand what type o problem it has and what is the solution?

If it have backend error then it will shows 500. but in logcat, lots of line runnig but not exectly problem shows. but some problem shows in emulator screen.

**This is api request**

```
Future<List<ListAlbum>> listData() async {
  final token = ""; //token data
  String url =
      'https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/getRequestedLeaveList?token=${token}';
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  final body = {'limit': 10, 'orderBy': 'idLeaveApplication', 'orderType': 'DESC'};
  final response = await dio.post(url, data: body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.data);

    return response.data["data"]["data"]
        .map<ListAlbum>((json) => ListAlbum.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed!');
  }
}
```

**Full Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LeaveList extends StatefulWidget {
  const LeaveList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LeaveListState createState() => _LeaveListState();
}

class _LeaveListState extends State<LeaveList> {
  late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  late Future<List<ListAlbum>> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = listData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<ListAlbum>>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print(snapshot.data);
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final ListAlbum item = snapshot.data![index];
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: Text(item.totalDay!.toString()),
                      title: Text(item.fullName!),
                      subtitle: Text(item.localHr!),
                      trailing: Text(item.submissionDate!),
                      onTap: () {
                        // Navigator.push(
                        //   context,
                        //   MaterialPageRoute(
                        //       builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        //           DetailsListOrganizationData()),
                        // );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ListAlbum {
  final int? idLeaveApplication;
  final int? idEmployee;
  final String? customID;
  final String? status;
  final String? lineSupervisor;
  final String? fullName;
  final int? totalDay;
  final String? submissionDate;
  final String? reportingSupervisor;
  final String? localHr;

  ListAlbum({
    this.idLeaveApplication,
    this.idEmployee,
    this.customID,
    this.status,
    this.lineSupervisor,
    this.fullName,
    this.totalDay,
    this.submissionDate,
    this.reportingSupervisor,
    this.localHr,
  });

  factory ListAlbum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ListAlbum(
      idLeaveApplication: json['idLeaveApplication'],
      idEmployee: json['idEmployee'],
      customID: json['customID'],
      status: json['status'],
      lineSupervisor: json['lineSupervisor'],
      fullName: json['fullName'],
      totalDay: json['totalDay'],
      submissionDate: json['submissionDate'],
      reportingSupervisor: json['reportingSupervisor'],
      localHr: json['localHr'],
    );
  }
}

Future<List<ListAlbum>> listData() async {
  // SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // final token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
  final token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI4OTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMxMjUxNjYwLCJleHAiOjE2MzEzMzgwNjAsIm5iZiI6MTYzMTI1MTY2MCwianRpIjoiNlFEUTZCYnBMT0JhdUJoaSJ9.jAY_2nYxjgsIvXZY5vn0vAr_pwF6UBYbSGZ8wqD0YPQ';
  String url =
      'https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/getRequestedLeaveList?token=${token}';
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  final body = {'limit': 10, 'orderBy': 'idLeaveApplication', 'orderType': 'DESC'};
  final response = await dio.post(url, data: body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.data);

    return response.data["data"]["data"]
        .map<ListAlbum>((json) => ListAlbum.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed!');
  }
}
```

**Error Emulator screen**
[image: Error in listview]

**so what is the solution?**

Comment: Please do hide your api url and accessToken. by looking at the error on your screenshot, it looks like wrongly formatted server error (500). For dio to correctly parse the response - it should be in json format. Contact your backend dev to format/transform errors to json

Comment: Thanks, api and token are just test porpuse. not live or original server.
but backend dev says, all okay though!

Comment: the backend has the error for being a 500 and sending the SQL error response